# Loading a bundle from Objective C class

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
public func dataFromFile(_ filename: String) -> Data? {
   @objc class TestClass: NSObject { }
   let bundle = Bundle(for: TestClass.self)
   if let path = bundle.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "json") {
      return (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)))
   }
   return nil
}
```

I found this code in a tutorial and am confused on what these two lines do:

```
@objc class TestClass: NSObject { }
let bundle = Bundle(for: TestClass.self)
```

I know we have the main bundle for the app but why is it creating a bundle for an objective c class called `TestClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know we have the main bundle for the app but why is it creating a bundle for an objective c class called TestClass?

The second bundle is usually a framework. Since the code is from a tutorial, likely the author wants to explain, what bundles are and how you access them.

Having a class you do not need to do that, because the runtime environment searches for the right bundle of a class. But if you want to load other resources (videos, images, sounds, and so on), you have to do it you own. To get the right bundle, you can ask a class residing there for its bundle.

Comment: But why does he mark the class as `@obj`? Why not just create a normal swift file in a class like in `Test.swift` we can put `class Test: NSObject { ... }`?

Comment: Ah, I understand. I think this is not necessary. Did you try it? Do you get an error?

Comment: Hmm yeah I tried it out and it seemed to work not sure which one to use or if he's just trying to show that an Objective-C type of class can also be passed into a Bundle or something.

Comment: Since the class is obviously an Objective-C typed class (it inherits from `NSObject`), there is little reason to add `@objc`. Maybe there are cases that are not that obvious. It's a tutorial.